# Ambiguous method overloading for method java.io.File#<init>. in React Native

Tags: java, android, reactjs, firebase, react-native

When I try to use command `react-native run-android` I see this error:

```
Ambiguous method overloading for method java.io.File#<init>.
  Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null, class java.lang.String] due to overlapping prototypes between:
        [class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String]
        [class java.io.File, class java.lang.String]
```

I was using this command `yard link` and this is my settings.gradle :

```
rootProject.name = 'ReactNativeTest'

include ':@react-native-firebase_firestore'
project(':@react-native-firebase_firestore').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/firestore/android')

include ':@react-native-firebase_app'
project(':@react-native-firebase_app').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/android')

include ':@react-native-firebase_auth'
project(':@react-native-firebase_auth').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth/android')


include ':app'
```

Clean app is working, but I want to use firebase.

Comment: just getting this in a different situation, but my guess so far is the first argument is `null` so it cannot disambiguate